# Register a user from any role in drupal 8

Tags: registration, drupal-8

In Drupal, only two roles can register a new user: administrator and anonymous.

Is it possible to register a user that another role can do and how?

Thank you for your help

Comment: can you tell us what you have tried before asking this question?

Answer (score -1):

look into permissions

admin/people/permissions

I think you want the user section/administer account settings. or administer users.